# How to call an instance of a class that makes an API call, and a function within that class that makes the request, and assign this to variable? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, class, async-await

This is a follow up to the following question: [Why isn't code being executed after/within a second URLSession.shared.dataTask, that is within an initial URLSession.shared.dataTask’s do block? Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72308605/why-isnt-code-being-executed-after-within-a-second-urlsession-shared-datatask/72329561?noredirect=1#comment127788962_72329561)

I’m trying to assign the current instance of a variable using `self.variable` to a function call from an instance of a class.

This can be seen at line of code starting with: “self.venues = “ in ViewController.swift in the attached code.

I believe `Task` has something to do with this. I’ve read the documentation about `Task`, and have read more about it online, but haven’t found the solution yet.

Also: I get the error message “Cannot assign value of type 'Task<(), Never>' to type '[Venue]'" at line of code starting with: “self.venues = “ in ViewController.swift.

Code:

`ViewController.swift`:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var venues: [Venue] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() async {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell")
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        let yelpApi = YelpApi(apiKey: "Api key")
        
        self.venues = Task {
            do { try await yelpApi.searchBusiness(latitude: selectedLatitude, longitude: selectedLongitude, category: "category query goes here", sortBy: "sort by query goes here", openAt: )

            }
            catch {
            //Handle error here.
            print("Error")
            }
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return venues.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        
        //Details for custom table view cell go here.
    }
        
    //Rest of table view protocol functions.
}
```

`Venue.swift`:

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - BusinessSearchResult
struct BusinessSearchResult: Codable {
    let total: Int
    let businesses: [Venue]
    let region: Region
}

// MARK: - Business
struct Venue: Codable {
    let rating: Double
    let price, phone, alias: String?
    let id: String
    let isClosed: Bool?
    let categories: [Category]
    let reviewCount: Int?
    let name: String
    let url: String?
    let coordinates: Center
    let imageURL: String?
    let location: Location
    let distance: Double
    let transactions: [String]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case rating, price, phone, id, alias
        case isClosed
        case categories
        case reviewCount
        case name, url, coordinates
        case imageURL
        case location, distance, transactions
    }
}

// MARK: - Category
struct Category: Codable {
    let alias, title: String
}

// MARK: - Center
struct Center: Codable {
    let latitude, longitude: Double
}

// MARK: - Location
struct Location: Codable {
    let city, country, address2, address3: String?
    let state, address1, zipCode: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case city, country, address2, address3, state, address1
        case zipCode
    }
}

// MARK: - Region
struct Region: Codable {
    let center: Center
}
```

`FetchData.swift`:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class YelpApi {
    
    private var apiKey: String
    
    init(apiKey: String) {
        self.apiKey = apiKey
    }
    
    func searchBusiness(latitude: Double,
                        longitude: Double,
                        category: String,
                        sortBy: String) async throws -> [Venue] {
        
        var queryItems = [URLQueryItem]()
        queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name:"latitude",value:"\(latitude)"))
        queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name:"longitude",value:"\(longitude)"))
        queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name:"categories", value:category))
        queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name:"sort_by",value:sortBy))
       
        var results = [Venue]()
        
        var expectedCount = 0
        let countLimit = 50
        var offset = 0
        
        queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name:"limit", value:"\(countLimit)"))
        
        repeat {
            
            var offsetQueryItems = queryItems
            
            offsetQueryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name:"offset",value: "\(offset)"))
            
            var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search")
            urlComponents?.queryItems = offsetQueryItems
            
            guard let url = urlComponents?.url else {
                throw URLError(.badURL)
            }
            
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.setValue("Bearer \(self.apiKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
            let businessResults = try JSONDecoder().decode(BusinessSearchResult.self, from:data)

            expectedCount = min(businessResults.total,1000)
            
            results.append(contentsOf: businessResults.businesses)
            offset += businessResults.businesses.count
        } while (results.count < expectedCount)
        
        return results
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an asynchronous operation - `searchBusinesses`. When you call this function, it takes time to get a result.  You are using `await` to handle this.

You can't use `await` outside of an asynchronous context, which `viewDidLoad` is not.  You are using a `Task` to create an asynchronous context.  So far so good.

Where you have gone wrong is trying to assign the result to `venues`.  You can only perform this assignment once the `await` completes.  You don't get this result *from* a `Task`, you get it *in* the `Task`:

```
Task {
    do { 
        self.venues = try await yelpApi.searchBusiness(latitude: selectedLatitude, longitude: selectedLongitude, category: "category query goes here", sortBy: "sort by query goes here", openAt: )
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    } catch {
            //Handle error here.
            print("Error")
    }
}
```

Note that you should not combine GCD dispatch queues and async/await and in this case, you don't need to worry about the main queue.

`UIViewController` is tagged `@MainActor`.  This means that Tasks are already executed on the main actor unless you specifically create a detached task.

Comment: Wow, thank you! This is very helpful and makes sense. Appreciate it!

Comment: Quick question: Do I need  to import UIKit at the top of FetchData.swift? I did some research on this; read some blogs and the Apple Developer Documentation for Foundation and UIKit, and it seems to me that I don't need to import UIKit here since UIKit deals more with creating and managing the user interface, whereas Foundation provides a base layer of functionality for the app and frameworks, including data storage and persistence, and networking, and many more things. Is this correct, in that I don't need to import UIKit at the top of FetchData.swift? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You don't need to import it if you don't use any UIKit classes (which it seems you don't).  Remove the import and if you don't get any errors you are good

Comment: Got it, makes sense. I removed the import, and didn't receive any errors, so it looks like I'm good. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi, I ran into another problem that I think is related to async/await; a new view controller isn't showing when I try to present it. I posted a new question for this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72511642/why-isn-t-the-table-view-from-a-new-view-controller-not-showing-swift if you'd like to take a look. I think it might be caused by not including the "override" before "func viewDidLoad() async {" in the specified view controller (in this question post, it's in ViewController.swift). Thanks so much for all the help!